# Checking difference between two date and display custom message

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Hello I have input on registration form and want to retrieve the value of input and compare it with the current date using JavaScript and display message after check age if age less than 18 year and display custom message on the bottom of input.

```
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]').getFullYear();
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value);
```

and this is the HTML

```
   <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" id="date1" value="{{ old('date', date('Y-m-d')) }} " onclick="checkDate()">
                            <div id="currentdate"></div>
```

but is give old value after each click.
and the message not displayed

Best regards

Comment: You'll need a bit more code.  Seen this often on SO where code gets the value outside the click event so never updates as the user updates.  This may or may not be the case here.

Comment: So what is the best way to do this constraint. thanks

Comment: I think @freedomn-m means you need to add more of your code so we can help determine the cause. What you posted isn't enough.

Comment: Yes, apologies if not clear:  You'll need to *provide* a bit more code, in your question, so that we can see it in context.

Comment: yes, already updated guys i add the html input date

Comment: Can you provide the *code* around the click event?  The HTML isn't relevant as it can be inferred (and isn't "code").   Where is your "var startDate..." that you have provided in relation to the `$(*something*).click(function()...` ?  And what's in `$(*something*).click(function()...`?

Answer (score 1):

Not much code to go from but I think you may need this function anyway to compare the date you receive from the form with the current date and get the difference

```
    function process() {
      var today = new Date();
      var date = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
      var diff = Number((today.getTime() - date.getTime()) / 31536000000).toFixed(0);
      if (diff >= 18) {
        // Your form submission goes here
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        // your error handeling goes here
        console.log("error");
      }
    }
```

> PS: **That this method won't give you the difference in an exact way,
> it will just give you the difference between the years.**

Comment: is give me  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

Comment: did you change `..ById("date")` to `..ById("date1")` to match *your* code?

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for the clarification

Comment: @SouhailMakni apologies, my comment was directed at Badr, though tailoring your answer to the question is always a good idea :)

Comment: @Badr No problems, I edited the answer to match the id in the question.